# HDFS disk is full

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, ambari

In our Ambari cluster, HDFS disk usage became 100%. I want to delete tables in HBase to free up disk but hbase (master) does not start.

I tried Hdfs re-balance but it faild. Another time I deleted HDFS files manually but after that HDFS didn't start anymore.

Is there a correct way to free disk space up? Or should I re-install ambari cluster?

HDP version is 2.4.2, HDFS version is 2.7.1 and Hbase is 1.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it's not perfect but it's better than re-installing everything!

Seemingly there is command that removes files from hdfs (hadoop fs), so we should use it to remove hbase data. The command is:

```
hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash /apps/hbase/*
```

where `/apps/hbase/` is path of hbase data in hdfs. *This command should run as **hdfs** user*.